# Fazer comparação usando String.Contains() desconsiderando o casing

Tags: c#, string, comparação, case-insensitive, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Preciso verificar se determinado termo existe dentro de uma string (em SQL é algo como `like '%termo%'`).

A questão é que preciso que isso seja feito sem considerar o *casing* das duas `strings`.

Como posso fazer isso? Existe algo nativo no .NET que permita esse tipo de comparação?

Por exemplo, todas comparações abaixo retornam **`false`**. Preciso de algo que faça com que elas retornem **`true`**:

```
var mainStr = "Joaquim Pedro Soares";

mainStr.Contains("JOA");
mainStr.Contains("Quim");
mainStr.Contains("PEDRO");
mainStr.Contains("PeDro");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É bem simples, use o [`IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) que tem um parâmetro indicando que deseja [ignorar a sensibilidade de caixa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Claro que ele retornará a posição de onde está o que quer saber se existe, mas aí é só verificar se o número é positivo, já que sabemos que um número negativo significa a não existência.

Tem quem faça um método de extensão para ficar disponível para o tipo `String` sempre que precisar. Há quem não goste. Se preferir fazer na mão, é só usar o que está dentro do método. Pode fazer um método de extensão que já use a opção de comparação fixa e não parametrize isto.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var mainStr = "Joaquim Pedro Soares";
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.Contains("JOA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.Contains("Quim", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.Contains("PEDRO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.Contains("PeDro", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}

namespace System {
    public static class StringExt {
        public static bool Contains(this string source, string search, StringComparison comparison) {
            return source.IndexOf(search, comparison) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/50yoVo). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zmmYNt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ContainsCaseInsensitive.cs).

É possível fazer algumas otimizações e melhorias, como verificar se os parâmetros são nulos ou vazios.

Comment: Se eu precisasse ignorar acentos, teria uma maneira para fazer isso tb?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida não, mas acho que dá uma boa nova pergunta :)

Comment: Pergunta feita: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179620/101

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é usa a classe [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) para verificar a string desconsiderado o casing, exemplo:

```
string foo = "Gato";
string bar = "gATo";                

bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(bar, foo, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(contains);
```

Saída:

> True

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2idpYg).

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3355561/5429980

Comment: Tem meu +1, mas eu quero distância de regex :p Brincadeiras a parte, é uma alternativa interessante mesmo.