# Fazer comparação usando String.Contains() desconsiderando acentos e case

Tags: c#, .net, string, acentuação, comparação

Preciso verificar como fazer uma comparação entre *strings*, em C#, utilizando o método `Contains()` que desconsidere tanto a **sensibilidade de acentos e a de *case*** de uma *string*.

Exemplo:

```
var mainStr = "Acentuação";

mainStr.Contains("acentuacao");
mainStr.Contains("ACENTUAção");
```

Ambas chamadas deveriam retornar true no caso

Comment: Relacionada: [Fazer comparação usando String.Contains() desconsiderando o casing](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179568/18246)

Comment: @bigown aunica diferença para q eu iria fazer é que eu iria usar o String.Compare, vc sabe se existe algum diferença de performance entre esses 2 métodos?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida não, precisaria testar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para ignorar a sensibilidade de caixa e os acentos não podemos usar nenhum método da classe `String` já que nenhum está preparado para isto. Mas podemos usar o mesmo [`IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Globalization_CompareInfo_IndexOf_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_System_Globalization_CompareOptions_) indicando que deseja [ignorar a sensibilidade de caixa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), mas ele deve ser da classe [`CompareInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que trabalha de acordo com a cultura e pode ignorar os acentos com a configuração certa. Claro que ele retornará a posição de onde está o que quer saber se existe, mas aí é só verificar se o número é positivo, já que sabemos que um número negativo significa a não existência.

Pode fazer um método de extensão para facilitar.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var mainStr = "José João";
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.ContainsInsensitive("JOA"));
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.ContainsInsensitive("jose"));
        Console.WriteLine(mainStr.ContainsInsensitive("josé"));
    }
}

namespace System {
    public static class StringExt {
        public static bool ContainsInsensitive(this string source, string search) {
            return (new CultureInfo("pt-BR").CompareInfo).IndexOf(source, search, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PkiUOc). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jjtKWd). Também [coloquei no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ContainsCaseAndAccentInsensitive.cs).

É possível fazer algumas otimizações e melhorias, como verificar se os parâmetros são nulos ou vazios.