# Comparar usando String.Contains() desconsiderando acentos e case

Tags: java, android, string, comparação, acentuação

Sei que já existe a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179620/fazer-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usando-string-contains-desconsiderando-acentos-e-case), até utilizei o mesmo título para chamar atenção, mas esta é referente á C#, estou tendo esse problema em java, código:

```
//historico e searchC são ArrayLists, no caso do case utilizei o 
//toUpperCase() para igualar, porém, em questão de acentos ele não retorna 
//nenhum valor, mesmo estando exatamente igual ao valor da linha do array
int i = 0;
    for (String[] linha : historico){
        if(linha[2].contains(nome.toUpperCase())) {
            searchC.add(historico.get(i));

        }
        i++;
    }
```

Caso a variável `nome` contenha qualquer tipo de acento, nenhum valor é retornado no `searchC`. Alguém sabe como fazer a comparação desconsiderando acentos e case diretamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptando [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745827/5524514), você pode utilizar a classe [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) para isso:

```
public boolean contanisIgnoreAccents(String a, String b) {
    String input1 = Normalizer.normalize(a, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
            .toLowerCase();

    String input2 = Normalizer.normalize(b, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
            .toLowerCase();

    return input1.contains(input2);
}
```

A comparação abaixo:

```
System.out.println(contanisIgnoreAccents("Este é joao", "João"));
System.out.println(contanisIgnoreAccents("Onde está joÂo", "João"));
```

retornará:

```
true
true
```

Como pode ser visto no ideone: https://ideone.com/cJcF6M

O método verifica se a segunda string passada como argumento está contida na primeira.¹

<sup>*¹ editei o exemplo para que fique claro a definição acima, pois se não for usado desta forma, o resultado poderá ser apresentado errado.*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a forma mais simples e rápida seria usar o **StringUtils** do [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

No build.gradle adiciona a dependência

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
}
```

Código Java

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public Boolean contanisIgnoreAccents(String a, String b) {

    // Remove os acentos e convert para minúsculo
    String str1 = StringUtils.stripAccents(a).toLowerCase();
    String str2 = StringUtils.stripAccents(b).toLowerCase();

    return str1.contains(str2);
}

public void onButtonClick {
    System.out.println(contanisIgnoreAccents("João", "joao"));
    System.out.println(contanisIgnoreAccents("João", "joÃo"));
}
```

Resultado

```
true
true
```

Código Kotlin

```
fun contanisIgnoreAccents(a: String, b: String) = (
    StringUtils.stripAccents(a).toLowerCase().contains(StringUtils.stripAccents(b).toLowerCase())    
)
```

Comment: Copiou meu exemplo :p

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele quer verificar se contem, não se é igual. Verificar se "Este é joão" contem "joao" irá retornar false nesse seu exemplo, mesmo contendo.

Comment: @Articuno, aproveitei o teu exemplo para mostrar de uma outra forma :D

Comment: Verdade! Fiz um equals e não um contains. Corrigindo o código!