# Dúvida sobre como posicionar botões

Tags: c#, winforms

As imagens são apenas ilustrativas.

O que eu preciso fazer, é o seguinte:

1. Estão vários botões com seus respectivos nomes, podendo ser
   chamados (clicados).
2. Eu digito o nome daquele botão no campo de **buscar jogo** e o
   resto dos botões somem. Ficando só aquele que eu digitei.

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Seria interessante que editasse e adicionasse na pergunta.

Comment: Então.. eu não sei por onde começar...

Comment: Mas você entendeu o que eu quero fazer?

Comment: Sim, mas sem um ponto de partida, a pergunta pode ser considerada ampla. Se não sabe por onde começar, seria interessante quebrar em duvidas menores, tentar criar um layout organizando os botoes e ir perguntando na medida que tiver dificuldades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demonstração do código funcionando:

[image: Demonstração]

---

Sua pergunta é bem simples e é muito fácil desenvolver uma solução para isso que você precisa.

Eu vou te dar uma base, o algoritmo praticamente pronto, você vai precisar adaptar algumas coisas e dar uma melhorada também. Tem muita que pode ser melhorada, o limite é sua imaginação.

Bem, vamos aos passos.

Sobre a "preparação"

1. Crie um painel para colocar estes botões referentes aos jogos. Se usar um `FlowLayoutPanel` os elementos serão reposicionados sempre da esquerda para a direita (veja a segunda imagem do próximo item). Isso vai facilitar encontrá-los e também vai permitir que você separe sua tela em diferentes pedaços. No meu exemplo, o painel se chama `mainPanel`.
2. Defina (em todos os botões) como cada um deles será identificado como determinado jogo. No exemplo, eu usei a propriedade [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) para definir isto e deixei a propriedade `Text` apenas para visualização (perceba que alguns botões mostram nomes abreviados, mas a busca funciona para o nome real do jogo).

   [image: Exemplo de form]

   A parte tracejada é o painel. Na imagem ao lado, a *properties tab*, atente para os valores das propriedades `Text` e `Tag` do último botão da primeira linha.

   O interessante de usar a propriedade `Tag`, é poder usar o nome real do jogo para fazer a busca, mas mostrar no botão apenas a sua abreviação. Por exemplo:

   [image: Exemplo de busca com nome completo do jogo]
3. Defina em que momento a busca vai acontecer. No exemplo, eu defini que a busca ocorreria sempre que o usuário digitasse algo no `TextBox` de busca, usando o evento [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Sobre o código

1. Na inicialização do form (no construtor, após o método `InitializeComponents()`), é preciso criar uma lista com todos os botões que existem dentro do painel principal. Isso vai permitir remover os botões do painel sem perdê-los, porque, por óbvio, vai ser necessário colocá-los lá de novo.
2. Agora vem a parte que faz o trabalho, a implementação do evento `TextChanged`. O algoritmo é simples e ingênuo.

   1. É feito um filtro na variável `_todosBotoes` (aquela que foi criada na inicialização do `form`) usando Linq, este filtro procura por botões cuja propriedade `Tag` **seja um texto e contenha** o texto que foi digitado pelo usuário. Eu ainda dei uma trabalhada e fiz com que a busca seja feita pela propriedade `Text`, **apenas se** o conteúdo da propriedade `Tag` for `null` ou não puder ser convertido pra `string`.
   2. Todos os controles do painel principal são removidos.
   3. Os controles retornados pelo filtro são adicionados no painel principal.
   4. Perceba que eu usei um método chamado `ContainsIgnoreCase()`. Este método não existe na classe `string`, é um método de extensão criado com base no [algoritmo desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179568/18246) e serve para que a comparação trate carácteres minúsculos e maiúsculos como os mesmos.

Segue o código

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Button[] _todosBotoes;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Passo 1
        _todosBotoes = mainPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
    }

    private void txtBusca_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Passo 2.1
        var controles = _todosBotoes.Where(bt => (bt.Tag as string ?? bt.Text).ContainsIgnoreCase(txtBusca.Text))
                                    .ToArray();

        // Passo 2.2
        mainPanel.Controls.Clear();

        // Passo 2.3
        mainPanel.Controls.AddRange(controles);
    }
}
```

Código do método `ContainsIgnoreCase()`

```
public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string search)
{
    return source.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu tenho uma dúvida, onde fica os botões dos jogos, eu não posso deixar eles soltos no form, como você mostrou, queria que eles pudessem ficar em uma espécie de caixa, com uma barra de rolagem.

Comment: @DárioSabaini Mas eu não deixei eles soltos. Estão em um painel, se quiser usar _scroll_ é só definir a propriedade `AutoScroll` como `true`.

Comment: bah é verdade, você usou o FlowLayoutPanel :), erro meu ! Pra ativar o scroll é só colocar pra true certo?

Comment: Sim[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201991/d%c3%bavida-sobre-como-posicionar-bot%c3%b5es/202064?noredirect=1#comment414582_202064)

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que você tenha uma base de dados (no código simulada por dtJogos), coloque um flowLayoutPanel no seu Form, um TextBox de pesquisa, e um timer que dispara a pesquisa, pode ser em um intervalo de 500ms por exemplo. O Evento TextChanged do TextBox reinicia o timer.

Segue o código:

```
    private DataTable dtJogos()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("nome");
        DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
        r["nome"] = "Diablo";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["nome"] = "Need For Speed";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["nome"] = "GTA";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["nome"] = "GRID";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["nome"] = "DIRT";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["nome"] = "Exemplo";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        return dt;
    }

    private void MontarBotoes()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        DataTable dt = dtJogos();

        DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("nome LIKE '" + textBoxPesquisa.Text + "%'");

        foreach (DataRow r in rows)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Name = r["nome"].ToString();
            b.Text = b.Name;
            b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 32);
            b.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1;
            b.Click += b_Click;
            b.Show();
        }
    }

    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nome = ((Button)sender).Name;
        //Processao Clique no botão do jogo
        MessageBox.Show("Você clicou no jogo: " + nome);
    }

    private void timerPesquisa_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerPesquisa.Enabled = false;
        MontarBotoes();
    }

    private void textBoxPesquisa_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerPesquisa.Enabled = false;
        timerPesquisa.Enabled = true;
    }
```