# Dúvida sobre procurar botões

Tags: c#, winforms

A ideia é:

1. No campo de "Buscar Jogo...", eu procuro pelos botões, que já estão nomeados com seus respectivos jogos: `btnArcheAge`, `btnDiablo3`, `btnWoW`, etc. As tags também já estão nomeadas com o real nome de cada jogo.
2. Quando eu busco "ArcheAge" por exemplo, o resto dos botões somem e só fica ele para ser clicável.

**Obs**: Os botões foram colocados em um `FlowLayoutPanel`

---

Preciso de um empurrãozinho com o código, não sei por onde começo. Essa é a foto que eu tenho do antigo post que fizeram pra mim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Programa e código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Button[] _todosBotoes;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Passo 1
        _todosBotoes = mainPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
    }

    private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(panel1.Width == 350)
        {    

            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Width = 65;

        }

    }

    private void btnVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(panel1.Width == 65)
        {

            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Width = 350;


        }

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (panel1.Width == 350)
        {
            btnVoltar.Hide();

        }
        else
        {

            btnVoltar.Show();
        }

    }

    public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string search)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }


    private void txtBuscarJogo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Passo 2.1
        var controles = _todosBotoes.Where(btnArcheAge => (btnArcheAge.Tag as String ?? btnArcheAge.Text).ContainsIgnoreCase(txtBuscarJogo.Text)).ToArray();
        //Passo 2.2
        mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
        //Passo 2.3
        mainPanel.Controls.AddRange(controles);
    }

    private void lblAmigos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade?

Comment: Exatamente como chamar um botão específico e os outros sumirem, assim que eu apago o que está escrito todos voltam. Igual que está na 1° gif. Não sei como chamar um botão, sendo o que está digitado no textbox.

Comment: Veja se este código te ajuda [How Can I Get The Button Controls in Windows Form - Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6421612)/1473534

Comment: O que você terá que fazer é colocar dentro do `txtBuscarJogo_TextChanged` funções com if e string contains, depois colocar para os butões que não contém desaparecerem e os que contem mudarem de posição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, eu fiz todo o código pra você [no outro post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202064/18246), só faltou você entender uma partezinha.

Como eu disse num dos itens

> Defina em que momento a busca vai acontecer. No exemplo, eu defini que a busca ocorreria sempre que o usuário digitasse algo no TextBox de busca, usando o evento `TextChanged`.

Você já tem o código que faz a busca (no outro post), agora só precisa colocá-lo dentro do evento `TextChanged` do `TextBox`. Pelos nomes no seu código, deve ser  o `txtBuscarJogo_TextChanged`.

Comment: Onde eu coloco esse public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string search)
{
    return source.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}

Comment: Onde você quiser.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f5l08m O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não sei, o print não mostra o erro.

Comment: Eu editei o código passado pelo atual la em cima. O erro é esse :http://prntscr.com/f5l1gr

Comment: Crie o método de extensão `ContainsIgnoreCase` numa classe estática (exatamente como o erro informa).

Comment: Deste jeito está certo.

Comment: Haha difícil usar isso, mas seria bem útil.. vou tentar mais aqui...

Comment: Mas abre outra pergunta com o erro de agora. Mas isola este erro, né. Mostra o código da extensão, o código que você usa o método e a mensagem de erro. Muito mais simples de te ajudar assim =)