# Como encontrar palavra reservada em uma frase?

Tags: c#, .net, string, contains

Estou criando uma rotina para buscar palavras reservadas em um texto (nome de pessoas). Já fiz testes com `Contains()` e `IndexOf()`. Funciona bem na maioria das vezes. No entanto em algumas palavras o retorno não satisfaz. Exemplo: no nome **CORALINA** retorna a palavra reservada **ORAL**.

Abaixo o código realizado:

```
    public JsonResult GetPalavrasReservada1(string frase)
    {
        var palavras = db.TBL_PALAVRA_RESERVADA.Where(pal => pal.PLR_ATIVO == 0).Select(i => new {i.PLR_DESC}).ToList();

        var palavrareservada = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < palavras.Count; i++)
        {
            if (frase.ToUpper().Contains(palavras[i].PLR_DESC.ToString()))
            {
                return Json(palavras[i].PLR_DESC.ToString());
            }
        }

        return Json(palavrareservada);
    }
```

Estou utilizando lógica ou métodos errados?

Comment: E não tá certo? De fato o nome "Coralina" contém a palavra "oral".

Comment: @LINQ não está de acordo com a definição de palavra aqui adotada. Você está pensando em substring, aqui uma palavra é um token devidamente delimitado. Como "coralina" forma um token só, ele não contém "oral"

Comment: Não seria o caso de verificar tem espaço em branco antes e depois da palavra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu usaria [Regex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) com o pattern `\d` para verificar a existência de palavras  inteiras na frase.

```
Regex.IsMatch("CAROLINE", @"\bORAL\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // false
Regex.IsMatch("Discurso oral", @"\bORAL\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // true
Regex.IsMatch("Nada consta contra", @"\bNada Consta\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // true
```

No seu código, ficaria assim:

```
if ( Regex.IsMatch(frase, "\\b" + palavras[i].PLR_DESC.ToString() + "\\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ))
```

Comment: Olá @Fernando, esta forma, utilizando o Regex.IsMatch acabou resolvendo o problema. Muito agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Se achar uma palavra reservada o algoritmo para e não acha outras, é isto que deseja?

Se deseja só pegar palavras inteiras tem que quebrar todas as palavras e fazer a verificação. Só que isto não é tão simples a não ser que controle o conteúdo do texto anteriormente e possa garantir que não tenha certos padrões. Se puder fazer isto quebrar a frase é só dar um [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_) pelo espaço e/ou outros caracteres que quebram uma palavra. Mas é improvável que não tenha situações de exceção a esta regra, aí teria que tratar tudo na mão. Obviamente que isto exigiria um laço extra para testar todas as palavras reservadas em todas palavras da frase.

Seria mais performática fazer um *parser* especializado, mas complica mais ainda.

Pode ser que um RegEx ajude, mas não gosto da ideia, é fácil fazer errado. Tem [exemplos no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31073799/221800) ([outro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3904645/221800) e [com LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31239536/221800)).

Um erro claro é usar o `ToUpper()`, isto não é correto. Veja [a forma mais correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179568/101).

A variável `palavrareservada` não tem função alguma neste código, pode ser eliminada.

Ficar pegando as palavras direto do banco de dados pode não ser a melhor estratégia.

Comment: Com relação a este problema fiz testes com a utilização do split e também regex que separam o texto em palavras e, neste caso, acaba resolvendo.
1. Com relação ao ToUpper() que você disse que está incorreto. Exatamente no que?
2. Se possuir uma palavra reservada com duas palavras (NAO CONSTA, por exemplo) o tratamento teria que ser diferente do que a utilizada com split ou regex.

Comment: É ineficiente e há casos (não em português, é verdade) que não dá o resultado esperado.