# Como separar uma string quando uma determinada palavra é iniciada?

Tags: c#

String:

`string str = "1234 5678 9012 ID: 123456789"`

Como posso separar a string quando a palavra "ID" for encontrada?

Ex:
`string[] formatted = {"1234 5678 9012", "ID: 123456789"}`

Comment: Ainda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251720/101